# reduce load time emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I' m using `emacs-25.0.50` on Mac OSX. I usually work with `emacsclient` so that load time is no issue for me.

However, I was curious to know why `emacs` needs 3.3 s to start up. (not so dramatic, but still curious)

Benchmarking yields:

```
Module              Type       ms [^]total ms                                                                                                                 
setup-package     require     185     192                                                                                                                     
log-edit          require     111     139                                                                                                                     
tramp-sh          require      65      265                                                                                                                     
cc-engine         require      59      59                                                                                                                     
helm-files        require      55     386                                                                                                                     
tramp-loaddefs    require      54      54                                                                                                                     
flycheck          require      53      83                                                                                                                     
mm-util           require      44      47
```

Two questions here:
1. I'm puzzled from where does the package `log-edit` come from. Is it necessary? In my `ini.el` file there is no hint where it is called
2. Is there any way to reduce the load time? `(require 'setup-package)` seems to be necessary, since the packages are checked at the startup.

Comment: Check out: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/what-can-i-do-to-speed-up-my-start-up/2291#2291

Comment: re: `log-init`, try `M-x unload-feature RET log-edit RET`, if something else `require`d it, you'll get an error message